InstructLab Commands not able to connect to server using granite model
Getting the following error when trying to run ilab serve and ilab generate commands
There was a problem connecting to the server Connection error
These are the commands used :
ilab generate --model models/granite-7b-lab-Q4_K_M
ilab serve --model-path models/granite-7b-lab-Q4_K_M.gguf --num-threads 14
Is there any workaround for this problem ?
Tried with merlinite-7b-lab-Q4_K_M and it is working fine.
